# Does any airport in the USA have a Canadian preclearance for traveler from USA to Canada?

Tags: usa, canada, airports, pre-clearance

Travelers to the USA from Canada are precleared while STILL in Canada if they are departing from [these Canadian airports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_border_preclearance#Air).

Is there currently (or will there be) any **US Airports** with *Canadian* preclearance for travelers departing from those US airports going to Canada?

Comment: preclearance works because a handful of airports (like 10 or 15 in Canada, and one in Ireland) can handle passengers headed to hundreds of different airports in the US, and spare those airports from having to process arriving passengers. It wouldn't work the other way around.

Comment: @KateGregory There are 2 in Ireland: Dublin and Shannon.

Comment: ok, but the point remains.

Comment: @KateGregory Why wouldn't it work the other way around?  If Canada put officers in US airports (like the US does in Canadian airports) they could pre-clear passengers exactly the same way.  They don't, but that doesn't mean they couldn't

Comment: @KateGregory also Abu Dhabi and several airports in the Caribbean: https://www.cbp.gov/travel/preclearance -- also, Midavalo is correct; the US/Canada preclearance agreement is reciprocal.  Canada could station officers in the US.  They don't, presumably because it is not cost effective as you note.

Comment: @Midavalo "it wouldn't work" because the costs don't justify the benefits.  It's not practical for Canada to send officers to hundreds of US airports.  Canada doesn't have large numbers of airports that handle domestic passengers but where there is also a demand for travel from (a relatively smaller number of) US airports.

Comment: @Midavalo by staffing a dozen Canadian airports the US can easily bring passengers to literally every airport in the US without having all the infrastructure associated with an "international airport". This makes flights to those airports possible. Canada gets that same effect by clearing people when they land. Fanning out to pre clear would increase their costs (and the airport's cost eg creating sterile areas) by two or more orders of magnidtude. There's no benefit. People don't want to fly direct from the US to a non-international Canadian airport.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There does not seem to be any US airport (or any other US port of exit) where Canadian authorities enforce any kind of preclearance. The [page of Public Safety Canada](https://www.publicsafety.gc.ca/cnt/brdr-strtgs/prclrnc/index-en.aspx) that describes the process does not mention any current enforcement of this preclearance by Canadian authorities.

However, [the currently active agreement](https://www.canada.ca/en/public-safety-canada/news/2019/08/new-canadaus-preclearance-agreement-comes-into-force-opening-door-to-enhanced-travel-and-trade.html) allows Canada to do so:

> It enables Canada and the U.S. to expand preclearance for travellers at land, rail and marine facilities in both countries, as well as at additional airports.

While there doesn't seem to be any Canadian preclearance enforced at the moment, there might be some at the future, without anything precise disclosed by the authorities:

> “Canada is committed to expanding preclearance and we continue to examine possibilities for expanding preclearance operations to new locations across our country and in the U.S.”
>
> – The Honourable Bill Blair, Minister of Border Security and Organized Crime Reduction